# Existe ambiguidade na frase abaixo?

Tags: ambiguidades

A frase abaixo é ambígua? Ela causou opiniões divergentes entre meus colegas, então resolvi postar aqui para ver se existe uma boa justificativa para ser ou não ser ambígua.

> "O mediador deve permitir que um jogador faça um movimento em até 5
> minutos"

Eu entendi que

> (1) o jogador deve fazer o movimento em até 5 minutos.

Teve gente achando que

> (2) o mediador tem até 5 minutos para permitir que o jogador faça um
> movimento.

Eu entendo que para cair no caso (2) é necessário colocar uma vírgula após "movimento". No entanto, mais uma vez, não tenho certeza disso.

Reformulando a frase com certeza não gera problemas, como nos dois casos abaixo:

> O mediador deve, em até 5 minutos, permitir que um jogador faça um
> movimento.
>
> O mediador deve permitir que um jogador faça, em até 5
> minutos, um movimento.

Comment: Não estou familiarizado com o uso de *em até*...

Comment: @JorgeB. parece mais ou menos equivalente a "dentro de".

Comment: Exatamente, @ANeves. No Brasil é bastante comum o uso de "em até" como equivalente a "dentro de".

Comment: @JorgeB. talvez _no máximo_ (não sei se é usado em pt-PT) também poderia se aplicar a este _em até_.

Comment: "em até" significa "dentro de, no máximo,..."

Comment: os cinco minutos estão muito longe do mediador para gerar tanta ambiguidade

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tua interpretação parece-me de longe a mais provável.

Assumo aqui que os movimentos são praticamente instantâneos. Uma das intrepretações (a tua) é esta:

> (1) O mediador deve permitir [que um jogador faça um movimento em até 5 minutos]

Tal como Jorge B., também acho muito estranho o uso de *em até*. Procurei a em textos brasileiros e encontrei frases deste género:

> O governo quer aprovar o projeto do rodízio em até três semanas.

Temos aqui *aprovar*, que é uma culminação, ou seja, um evento breve com um estado resultante, portanto um predicado aspetualmente semelhante a *fazer um movimento*, pelo menos na minha interpretação destes movimentos. E, nesta frase, *em até* dá um **prazo** para determinado evento ocorrer. Assumindo que o valor de *em até* é semelhante na frase (1), podemos parafraseá-la desta forma:

> (2) É permitido o jogador fazer um movimento nos 5 minutos seguintes.

Passemos para a outra interpretação, em que *em até 5 minutos* é adjunto do predicado da oração matriz:

> (3) O mediador deve permitir [que um jogador faça um movimento] em até cinco minutos.

Esta frase tem em si duas interpretações possíveis. Podemos ver *permitir* como um predicado aspetualmente com duração (a permissão estende-se no tempo):

> (4) O mediador permite, durante os 5 minutos seguintes, que o jogador faça um movimento.

caso em que o significado é essencialmente igual a (2). Ou podemos ver *permitir* como algo pontual:

> (5) O ato de dar permissão para o movimento do jogador tem de ser feito no prazo máximo de 5 minutos.

A frase (4) parece ir contra o significado de *em até* que vimos antes, mas como não estou muito familiarizado com a construção, não posso dizer se (4) está completamente posto de parte.

A interpretação de frase (5), que tem de facto um significado diferente de (2), parece-me bastante improvável. Tu dás algumas razões gramaticais (há posições para o adjunto menos ambíguas, a distância ao predicado com a ausência de vírgula), mas as razões mais fortes parecem-me semânticas.

Aceitando que *deve* significa *tem de*, i.e, que a permissão não é discricionária, aceitar (5) é aceitar que regras estabelecem um prazo de 5 minutos para o juiz executar uma ação não discricionária. Não estamos a falar de um prazo para o juiz tomar uma decisão, caso em que poderia precisar de tempo. Parece-me, portanto, bem mais provável que a frase original indique um prazo durante o qual dada ação do jogador é legal.

Comment: Como comentei há pouco, você pode tratar "em até" como sinônimo para "dentro de".

Answer (score 0):

Há ambiguidade, mas ela é muito fraca, na minha opinião. Isso se deve ao fato de que "permitir" não é uma ação que possa durar. Você pode "escrever em cinco minutos", mas "permitir em cinco minutos" é meio forçado, pra mim. É simplesmente ou sim ou não e ponto.

Só é possível existir uma ambiguidade aí se a pessoa entender "permitir" como "decidir". Aí sim o mediador poderia "decidir em 5 minutos".

Comment: O -1 não é meu, mas creio que a ambiguidade principal não é essa. É entre «em até 5 minutos» se referir à permissão ou à execução movimento. Se a permissão durar 5 minutos, isso é equivalente a haver uma permissão para executar o movimento em 5 minutos, por isso é ambiguidade estrutural, que é a que referes, desemboca no mesmo resultado.